# Unstable cache after upgrading to TYPO3 v. 10.4

Tags: caching, typo3, upgrade, typo3-10.x

After upgrading a site with TYPO3 version 8.7 via v. 9.5 to version 10.4.2, the cache is "unstable" for lack of a better word. The problem is that after a few hours the cache contains faulty pages. That is, the links are either generated without the href attribute or with another language, i.e. /fr/ instead of /de/.

The fix: empty cache via install tool.

Approach:

1. stopped all back-end work, error persists,
2. checked and changed cache configuration to 'database', to no avail,
3. disabled caching 'no_cache = 1', no faulty pages are produced.

Question: What produces the faulty pages in the cache after a few hours? Are there possibly 'left-over-configurations' or settings from the version 8.7?

config.yaml

```
base: 'https://metu.de'
baseVariants: {  }
errorHandling: {  }
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF8
    iso-639-1: de
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    flag: de
    languageId: '0'
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.UTF8
    iso-639-1: en
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: us
    languageId: '1'
  -
    title: French
    enabled: true
    base: /fr/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: fr_FR.UTF8
    iso-639-1: fr
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: fr
    languageId: '2'
  -
    title: Italian
    enabled: true
    base: /it/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: it_IT.UTF8
    iso-639-1: it
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: it
    languageId: '4'
  -
    title: Russian
    enabled: true
    base: /ru/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: ru_RU.UTF8
    iso-639-1: ru
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: ru
    languageId: '5'
  -
    title: Spanish
    enabled: true
    base: /es/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: es_ES.UTF8
    iso-639-1: es
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: ''
    hreflang: ''
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: es
    languageId: '3'
rootPageId: 1
routes: {  }
websiteTitle: Metu
```

Comment: I don't have a definitive idea. But as you switched to "Site Handling", the older  TypoScript variables can (should) be removed: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.2/Feature-84581-SiteHandling.html. Also the deprecation log and the "Scan Extension Files" (in the "Upgrade" module/InstallTool) might give clues if some older code does something weird language related. Also check your page slugs (are they unique?). I suggest you post your site config .yaml to your question because that is where routing happens since TYPO v9

Comment: Thank You, very much Jonas. I've removed the language TypoScript variables from the templates and enabled the depreciation log. There is one installed extension only, ke_search which produces some warnings.

Comment: Thank you for adding the .yaml. What looks suspicious is the `typo3Language: default` on multiple languages. Usually the language with `languageId=0` is the default language but I am not sure if that could lead to problems.

Comment: That is certainly a valid point. Thank you very much. It's worth a try. I hope I can edit the yaml file with the vi because it was generated by TYPO3.

Comment: it happens by clicking thru the site, the links are off (language) or generated with empty anchor tags. One click and suddenly the cache renders a faulty page. config.yaml is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues when upgrading Typo3 from v 7.6 to v 10.4. Removing the old typoscript language configuration (config.linkVars, conditions with GP:L etc.) fixed them.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I need the conditions [globalVar = GP:L = n] for generating the language menu. I hope there's a new way to do it. Again, thank you very much. I'm glad you had the same problem.